# Javascript and Frames

Tags: javascript, frameset

A few other users were kind enough to help me and it was much appreciated, but now I have one more question that I was unable to to do correctly. Again, I'm not much of a javascript guru, but I am trying to help a family member, so the simpler I can understand it, the better :p : This is the original website's code fixed and working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Chapter 8: Question 1</title>

<script type="text/javascript">
 function updatebox()

 {
 var textbox = document.getElementById("list")
 var total = 0
 textbox.value = ""



 if(document.getElementById('A1').checked) {
total += 5;
}

 else if(document.getElementById('A1')) {
total += 0;
}

if(document.getElementById('A2').checked) {
total += 5;
    }

  else if(document.getElementById('A2')) {
total += 0;
    }

if(document.getElementById('A3').checked) {
total += 5;
    }

 else if(document.getElementById('A3')) {
total += 0;
    }

if(document.getElementById('R1').checked) {
total += 0;
    }

 else if(document.getElementById('R1')) {
total += 0;
    }

if(document.getElementById('R2').checked) {   
total += 50
    }

else if(document.getElementById('R2')) {
total += 0;
    }

if(document.getElementById('R3').checked) {
total += 100;
    }

else if(document.getElementById('R3')) {
total += 0;
    }

var drop1 = document.getElementById("proc");

if(drop1[drop1.selectedIndex].value=="P1"){
total += 0;
}
else if(drop1[drop1.selectedIndex].value=="P2"){
total += 50;
}
else if(drop1[drop1.selectedIndex].value=="P3"){
total += 100;
}   
var drop2 = document.getElementById("hard");

if(drop2[drop2.selectedIndex].value=="H1"){
total += 0;
}
else if(drop2[drop2.selectedIndex].value=="H2"){
total += 30;
}
else if(drop2[drop2.selectedIndex].value=="H3"){
total += 45;
}   

textbox.value = total;



}  


</script>

</head>
<body>
<form>
Processor
<br />
<select name="Processor" onchange="updatebox()" id="proc">
<option value="P1">MegaPro 10ghz ($0.00)</option>
    <option value="P2">MegaPro 12ghz (+$50.00)</option>
    <option value="P3">MegaPro 15ghz (+$100.00)</option>
</select>   
<br />
<br />
Hard drive
<br />
<select name="cboHardDrive" onchange="updatebox()" id="hard">
     <option value="H1">30tb (+$0.00)</option>
     <option value="H2">40tb (+$30.00)</option>
     <option value="H3">60tb (+$45.00)</option>
</select>
<br />
<br />
CD-ROM (+$5.00)
<input type="checkbox" name="chkCDROM" id="A1" onclick="updatebox()" />
<br />
DVD-ROM (+$5.00)
<input type="checkbox" name="chkDVD" id="A2" onclick="updatebox()" />
<br />
Scanner (+$5.00)
<input type="checkbox" name="chkScanner" id="A3" onclick="updatebox()" />
<br />
<br />
<input id="R1" type="radio" name="case" value="desktopcase" onclick="updatebox()" />      Desktop Case (+$0.00)<br />
<input id="R2" type="radio" name="case" value="minitower" onclick="updatebox()" /> Mini     Tower (+$50.00)<br />
<input id="R3" type="radio" name="case" value="fulltower" onclick="updatebox()" /> Full         Tower (+$100.00)<br />
<br />
$<input id="list" type="text" name="list" size="1" disabled = "disabled"     placeholder="0" />

</form>
</html>
```

What, I need to do, is take that page and combine it with framesets (yes, I know it's not preferred, but it's what need to happen) using the page I made and put the results in the blank page without changing the code in the page I made above.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Frameset//EN" 
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-frameset.dtd">

 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
 <title>frameset</title>
 </head>
 <frameset cols="55%,*">
 <frame src="change.html" name="pickSystem">
 <frame src="about:blank" name="systemSummary">
 </frameset>
 </html>
```

According to the assignment she is doing, I should be using document objects close() and open() but I'm not entirely sure where to put this.

There's probably something I'm missing, I'm just not seeing it. If I could show pictures I would, but I can't.

Any and all help is appreciated, especially by me.

Comment: "It's what needs to happen"? Why?? Framesets are deprecated. They are useless.

Comment: It's the way the school wants it.

Comment: If a school wanted to me to do something like that, I'd drop out. You could get a better education on google.

Comment: have you kept your <body> tag in different files?
i think its solve your problem

Comment: The teacher is probably just introducing the concept of frames, just so they know how to do them. I'm not the teacher, I'm just trying to help someone to understand it.

Comment: Vimal, I was kind of thinking of taking the javascript stuff and putting it into a seperate file similar to CSS and linking it to the frames page and linking it back the change.html page, think that would help?

Comment: I've added parent.pickSystem.updatebox() to the frames page to be able to call upon the code in the change.html page, any suggestions on being able to add it that second blank page?